# Split using regex considering only first occurence of the regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex, split

here is my code to split a string patter based on regex match.

```
string[] docPath = Regex.Split("\\\\sds\\dsd\\df\\df\\d\\fd\\D\\sd\\asdsf\\sdf\\D\\dsfsd", @"[\\][A-Z][\\]");
```

The above code splits input string (hardcoded) into 3 parts i.e

1. \\sds\dsd\df\df\d\fd
2. sd\asdsf\sdf
3. dsfsd

I want it to split only on the **first** occurrence. output i want is :

1. \\sds\dsd\df\df\d\fd
2. sd\asdsf\sdf\D\dsfsd

Can anyone please help me to modify the reg expression? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the version of `Regex.Split()` that's an instance method which takes a number specifying the maximum number of components to split into:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[\\][A-Z][\\]");
string[] docPath = pattern.Split(
   "\\\\sds\\dsd\\df\\df\\d\\fd\\D\\sd\\asdsf\\sdf\\D\\dsfsd", 2);
```